# Neural networks: generating g prime(z) in back propagation

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation

I am doing Andrew Ng's excellent new Deeplearning course. I have an issue with implementing back propagation in a one hidden layer network that looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to derive the derivative of Z1 using the formula:

[image]

My understanding is that g prime Z1 in this formula is the derivative of g(z) with respect to Z which I believe is

```
    sigmoid(Z) * (1-sigmoid(Z))
```

where the function sigmoid generates the sigmoid function with respect to Z.
My final equation looks like this:

```
  dZ1 = np.dot(W2.T, dZ2) * (sigmoid(Z1)*(1-sigmoid(Z1)))
```

Where Z1 is the output of the first (and only) hidden layer.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong (except `Z1` is not the output of the layer, it is the "logit" and `A1` is the output, `A1 = sigmoid(Z1)`). What is happening that makes you think your code is wrong?

Comment: The course provides expected answers which up to this point, I have been getting right. However, for this section of the exercise, my result for all parameters that involve dZ1 are wrong (but the other parameters are correct).

Comment: OK, I think I see the problem. You have made an incorrect assumption about the network architecture, take a look at the feed-forward logic again. I don't want to break the course honour code and spell it out. Note I made the same error in my previous comment, because I assumed you were correct  . . .

Comment: I took the course too. The honour code suggests that I should not actually debug or write answers directly on coursework, but I think hints and general knowledge about backprop are OK. So also asking about a similar network you were implementing in a different approach or "why does it work like this" are fine. I suggest don't post your answer here because that would be publishing a partial answer to course materials.

Comment: If you have enough time to write about a *different* network, without using the course materials, but with the same mistake in backprop, then I think a self-answer would be fine here, and not a violation of course honour code. There are literally dozens of posts like that here, that anyone could look up. However, it may not be worth your time.